# Gnuplot with text data value

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have the following data stored in `file.txt`

```
111  a
333  b
555  c
888 space
```

how to plot this data so that the y axis will be labeled

`a b c space`

because when i tried to plot it, both axis take numeric values

using `plot 'file.txt'`

any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks ugly but probably answers your question:

```
plot [][0:1000] 'file.txt' using 1:xtic(2)
```